# How to force the Google Chart Legend to show Row values?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, legend

I hope this question can be understood as I find this topic rather tricky to explain. What I am looking for is a solution for a **Google (Column) Chart**, in which the chart **shows both, X-Axis and legend with values**, like a pie chart sometimes does. Most examples I found simply turned off the legend, though.

Here is what I got so far: First example of the fitting x axis:

[image]

The legend just shows 'Density', which makes sense, but I am looking for all the metals in the legend as well. So I switched the order of the dataset, to end up with this one:

[image]

And here the x axis shows density instead of the metals. So what I am looking for is something like this:

[image]

Either way, be it the manipulation of the legend or the manipulation of the axis works for me. Any ideas how to proceed?

### Sources

First version

```
function drawChart() {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ["Element", "Density", { role: "style" } ],
        ["Copper", 8.94, "#b87333"],
        ["Silver", 10.49, "silver"],
        ["Gold", 19.30, "gold"],
        ["Platinum", 21.45, "color: #e5e4e2"]
      ]);

      var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
      view.setColumns([0, 1,
                       { calc: "stringify",
                         sourceColumn: 1,
                         type: "string",
                         role: "annotation" },
                       2]);

      var options = {
        title: "Density of Precious Metals, in g/cm^3",
        width: 600,
        height: 400,
        bar: {groupWidth: "95%"},

      };
      var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("columnchart_values"));
      chart.draw(view, options);
  }
```

My Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/927pjLvb/2/

Second version:

```
function drawChart() {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
       ["Element", "Copper", "Silver", "Gold", "Platinum"],
       ["Density", 8.94, 10.49, 19.30, 21.45],

      ]);

      var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
      view.setColumns([
      0,
      1,
                       { calc: "stringify",
                         sourceColumn: 1,
                         type: "string",
                         role: "annotation" },
            2,
                                    { calc: "stringify",
                         sourceColumn: 2,
                         type: "string",
                         role: "annotation" },                 
      3,
                                    { calc: "stringify",
                         sourceColumn: 3,
                         type: "string",
                         role: "annotation" },                 
      4,
                                    { calc: "stringify",
                         sourceColumn: 4,
                         type: "string",
                         role: "annotation" }
      ]);

      var options = {
        title: "Density of Precious Metals, in g/cm^3",
        width: 600,
        height: 400,
        colors: ['#b87333', 'silver', 'gold', '#e5e4e2'],
        bar: {groupWidth: "95%"},

      };
      var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("columnchart_values"));
      chart.draw(view, options);
  }
```

My fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8jaL9kf3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

starting with the second version, leave the x-axis label blank.

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['Element', 'Copper', 'Silver', 'Gold', 'Platinum'],
  ['', 8.94, 10.49, 19.30, 21.45]
]);
```

on the chart's `'ready'` event,
copy the labels from the legend,
and place them under the bars,
using chart method --> `getChartLayoutInterface()`

the layout interface has method --> `getBoundingBox(id)`
this method returns the coordinates of chart elements,
by passing the id of the element.
in this case, we want to know the coordinates of the bars.
the id of each bar is structured as follows.

```
'bar#0#0'  // <-- first bar
```

where the first `0` is the series number, and the second row number.
once we know the coordinates of the bars,
we can place the copied labels under them.

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages:['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Element', 'Copper', 'Silver', 'Gold', 'Platinum'],
    ['', 8.94, 10.49, 19.30, 21.45]
  ]);

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([0, 1, {
    calc: 'stringify',
    sourceColumn: 1,
    type: 'string',
    role: 'annotation'
  }, 2, {
    calc: 'stringify',
    sourceColumn: 2,
    type: 'string',
    role: 'annotation'
  }, 3, {
    calc: 'stringify',
    sourceColumn: 3,
    type: 'string',
    role: 'annotation'
  }, 4, {
    calc: 'stringify',
    sourceColumn: 4,
    type: 'string',
    role: 'annotation'
  }]);

  var options = {
    title: 'Density of Precious Metals, in g/cm^3',
    width: 600,
    height: 400,
    colors: ['#b87333', 'silver', 'gold', '#e5e4e2'],
    bar: {groupWidth: '95%'},
  };

  var container = document.getElementById('columnchart_values');
  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(container);

  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function (gglClick) {
    // chart svg
    var svg = container.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];

    // chart layout
    var chartLayout = chart.getChartLayoutInterface();

    // get all chart labels, chart title will be first, legend labels next
    var labels = container.getElementsByTagName('text');

    // process each series in the data table
    for (var series = 1; series < data.getNumberOfColumns(); series++) {
      // get bar bounds
      var barBounds = chartLayout.getBoundingBox('bar#' + (series - 1) + '#0');

      // copy legend label
      var barLabel = labels[series].cloneNode(true);

      // padding above label
      var labelPadding = 4;

      // center align label
      barLabel.setAttribute('text-anchor', 'middle');

      // set label x,y coordinates
      barLabel.setAttribute('x', barBounds.left + (barBounds.width / 2));
      barLabel.setAttribute('y', barBounds.top + barBounds.height + parseFloat(barLabel.getAttribute('font-size')) + labelPadding);

      // add label to chart svg
      svg.appendChild(barLabel);
    }
  });

  chart.draw(view, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="columnchart_values"></div>
```

note: the above example assumes the chart will have a title option.

Comment: Yes, the charts do get a title and much more series, so this beauty works wonderful as it is already dynamic. I've never thought one can dig that deep into google guts, loving it :)